# How to launch and get the results from another application using an application in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Well, I am developing an application and it needs results from another application. This secondary application is a full-fledged application and is independent. So, is it possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Edit: It's an entirely different application. Still, I know that secondary application writes content at a particular application and that's all I know. As for the calling application, is it really possible to just call the installed application present in the system? WinHttptrack website. I need to call that application and store the written files somewhere and these files should be accessed in my visual studio application. This is my requirement.

Second edit: I can use process. start from the system diagnostics, to start my desired application but it needs a manual input of project name, url and such. How am I supposed to pass them?

Comment: You'll have to give a lot more information. At the moment all anyone can say is: "sure it is possible", but I think that's not your actual question.

Comment: Yes it is possible. But you really need to give some specifics if you want help here with it. For example, App 1 could write its output to stdout and App 2 could read it. App 1 could write a file. App 2 could read it. App 1 could offer a rest service. App 2 could do a get.....infinite possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

References are useful for example building a test app that validates a different projects(each project is technically its own application) local data within Visual Studio.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Alternatively you could consider exposing the data in some format such as .json or xml to share data between the apps or even look at employing a database driven system

You may also want to consider taking a look at Entity Framework:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696172(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: If this has answered the question please mark it as such otherwise please give more clarity to the question so that an appropriate answer can be given as soonest possible to benefit others that may have had the same or similar question.

Comment: I have edited that question a bit. Sorry for the late reply.